# Using Excel 2016, how do I get to the cell which is defined using Address() function

Tags: excel-formula

Using the Address() function, I have established a cell containing the address of another cell that contains the information I want.

How do I "GoTo" that cell, and read its data so that I can use it.

=IF(M28="Fri",ADDRESS(28,13+1),ADDRESS(28,14+1)

Result is a cell with the address for Saturday data which is at  **$K$28**

K28 has data that I want to act on / use.

I tried various tools match/index/lookup/cell etc but failed !!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to **see** the contents of the target cell, then use the dazzathedrummer answer.  If you want to **jump to** the target cell, then replace your formula with:

```
=HYPERLINK("#" & IF(M28="Fri",ADDRESS(28,13+1),ADDRESS(28,14+1)),IF(M28="Fri",ADDRESS(28,13+1),ADDRESS(28,14+1)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Indirect()

```
Indirect(=IF(M28="Fri",ADDRESS(28,13+1),ADDRESS(28,14+1)))
```

This will give you the value in the cells specified in the if.